# Flutter app run stuck white screen on device

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

i've developed a an app on flutter, despite it worked 2 days ago, when i run the app on the device the application it does not start. It remains on the white screen and do not launch the app. I think that something happened when i synchronized the gradle.

My main.dart:

```
import 'package:my_firstapp/locator.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:my_firstapp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setupServices();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Color(0xff5FA55A),
          accentColor: Color(0xff5FA55A),
        ),
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.my_firstapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="food_track"
        android:icon="@drawable/launch_background">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.my_firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.aptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I checked that everything is upgraded and it is. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal, cd to android folder of your flutter project and run:

```
$./gradlew build
```

Comment: i've got an error: Caused by: image_picker.andtoid. java.io.FileNotFoundException at ImageResizerTest.java:70

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in the file should be: image_picker.android

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean in the profile.dart?